# How to disable a route based on a condition

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route set up for a menu

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SalesOverviewNewPage } from "./inner-components";

export const DashboardPage = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="flexRow full p-0 m-0">
      <div className='full-flex flexCol width100 p-0 m-0'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="sales-overview-new" />} />
          <Route path="/sales-overview-new" element={<SalesOverviewNewPage />} />
          <Route path="/devices-overview" element={null} />
          <Route path="/perfomance" element={null} />
          <Route path="/sales-datewise" element={null} />
          <Route path="/top-items-more" element={null} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

i need to make the menu items which doesn't have a component available to be still present in the submenu but to become disabled sort of based on a condition which isa always same.In the above code for which ever route that has null value as element i need to disable it. Is there a way to do this instead of removing the routes which has null value as elements.

Comment: What menu items are you referring to in the code snippet? What are you trying to disable or enable based on a condition? Can you [edit] to clarify what any specific issue is that you face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to create a route object and use it in both places DashboardPage and Navigation.

Create an object of your routes like below:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    text: '',   //this will be the link text
    component: <Navigate replace to="sales-overview-new" />,   // Or keep this null
    path: '/',
  },
  {
    text: 'Sales Overview New',   //this will be the link text
    component: <SalesOverviewNewPage />,   // Or keep this null
    path: '/sales-overview-new',
  },
  {
    text: 'Sales Overview New',   //this will be the link text
    component: null,   // Or keep this null
    path: '/sales-overview-new',
  }
]
```

Next, import these routes in the DashboardPage and create Routes like this:

```js
<Routes>
  routes.map(route => (
    //I am using the key as routes.path as most of the times it will be unique, you can use index or any other value.
    <Route key={routes.path} path={routes.path} element={routes.component} />
  ));
</Routes>
```

Then, import and use the same routes object while rendering the links:

```js
<nav>
  routes.map(route => (
    route.component !== null ? 
      //Normal link  : 
      //Disabled link
  ));
</nav>
```

Modify and style disabled link and normal links as per your requirements.